# WPF - Open Message Box while another Message Box is open

Tags: wpf, async-await, task, messagebox

Hi I am testing some stuff for my program, everytime a test is complete a new Message Box should show.
The problem is that only a new Message Box will open after I closed the Message Box before that.
I tried putting the Message Box into a new Task, but that did not work either...

```
Task.Run(() => System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
                dirs[directory] + " is done, it took " + stopwatch.Elapsed,
                "Done with " + dirs[directory],
                System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK,
                System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Information,
                System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.OK,
                System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification));
```

I also tried to make the method async and await Task.Run, no luck there too

```
 await Task.Run(() => System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
                dirs[directory] + " is done, it took " + stopwatch.Elapsed,
                "Done with " + dirs[directory],
                System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK,
                System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Information,
                System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.OK,
                System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MessageBox.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show) invokes [MessageBox function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox).

On the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox#remarks) you can read:

> If you create a message box while a dialog box is present, use a handle to the dialog box as the `hWnd` parameter. The `hWnd` parameter should not identify a child window, such as a control in a dialog box.

But you can't get the `hWnd` of a message box.

You're better of creating a custom window for this.

Comment: sad that it wont work the way i wanted it to, but still thank you :)